# Deserialize JSON to Java Object containg Collection using Jackson

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jackson, deserialization

I am making a very simple test with Jackson. I have a class and use its object as parameter and return value of a Jersey method. 
The class is :

```
import java.util.List;

public class TestJsonArray {

    private List<String> testString;

    public List<String> getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(List<String> testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }
}
```

I have a Jersey method that tries to add one string to the list test string

```
@Path("/arrayObj")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object createObjectArray(@QueryParam("param") String object) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestJsonArray convertValue = objectMapper.convertValue(object, TestJsonArray.class);
        convertValue.getTestString().add("hello");
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(convertValue);
    }
```

When I call this method with the parameter

> {"testString":["Hi"]}

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not construct instance of test.rest.TestJsonArray, problem: no suitable creator method found to deserialize from JSON String
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

The exception is thrown in the deserialization processs:

> TestJsonArray convertValue = objectMapper.convertValue(object,
>   TestJsonArray.class);

I am wondering why this Exception is thrown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did u create `TestJsonArray` just to hold `ArrayList`? or it contains other fields?

Comment: this is just a test form my real application. My real application contains also other fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `readValue` method of `ObjectMapper` instead of `convertValue`

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, TestJsonArray.class);
```

this should work.

Comment: I think I am doing it in :  `TestJsonArray convertValue = objectMapper.convertValue(object, TestJsonArray.class);`. I have tested it also with an input as JSONObject, but still doesnt work

Comment: don't use `convertValue` it throws exception, use `readValue` method. See my post.